# Fischi.de/usbasp programmer

Tags: programmer, usbasp

I have constructed the usbasp programmer that is described on the https://www.fischl.de/usbasp/ website. I uploaded the firmware to the atmega8  using an arduino uno and avrdudess I set the hfuse to 0xc9 and lfuse to 0xef, the firmware uploaded.

I then put the atmega8 chip into my diy programmer and plugged it into a USB port on my computer. I am getting a message "usb device not recognised". I downloaded Zadig 2.4 to install the driver but when I click on all options I get a message similar to the windows "usb device no recognised".

I used a multimeter to check all my connections on the continuity setting and all appears to be ok. When I power up the programmer the leds don’t work. I removed the atmega8 and shorted the led to ground both leds lit up.

Any help would be appreciated! 
Thanks to all.

Comment: *described on the fiscal website* is that something to do with tax or money? Try using standard grammar like full-stops between sentences and consider adding a paragraph or two to make the read easier. *Any help would be appreciated* - that's OK.

Comment: Sorry Andy won’t post any more threads I don’t want to upset any one

Comment: Honestly you are probably better off just using the Arduino as an ISP in the way you used it to bootstrap this project.  Using non-USB parts to bitbang USB is complex and known to lead to edge cases where it doesn't work.  Then add to that the possibility that something is wrong with the implementation of the circuit itself.  There's really nothing in your question which could be used to provide an "answer" in the way that this site is intended to work, all anyone can really say is to double check everything and pursue it with whoever published the project you are following.

Comment: You are probably right Chris just wanted to try and make one